# Making a flask button that updates my SQL db file

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask, button

I'm trying to make an index file that displays two tables:

1. users account details (done)
2. equipment the user has borrowed.

In the second table, I'm trying to add a button that allows the users to return the borrowed equipment (by updating the data file in my SQL file).

Python (app.py file):

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def index():
#Table 1 (Done)
    rows1 = db.execute("SELECT name AS n FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
    row1 = rows1[0]
    name = (row1["n"])
    rows2 = db.execute("SELECT user_id AS i FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
    row2 = rows2[0]
    user_id = (row2["i"])
    rows3 = db.execute("SELECT phone AS p FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
    row3 = rows3[0]
    phone = (row3["p"])

#Table 2
    borrowed = db.execute("SELECT equipments.eqp_name, timestamp, purpose, transactions.details, transactions.eqp_serial, return_date FROM transactions JOIN equipments ON equipments.eqp_serial = transactions.eqp_serial WHERE user_id = ? AND availability = 2", session["user_id"])

**    if request.method == "POST":
        # TODO**
    else:
        return render_template("index.html", name = name, user_id = user_id, phone = phone, borrowed = borrowed)
```

HTML (index.html file)

```
    </table>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr style="background-color: #D6DBDF">
            <th>Items borrowed</th>
            <th>Serial</th>
            <th>Borrow Date</th>
            <th>Expected Return Date</th>
            <th>Purpose</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Return</th>

        </tr>
        <!--equipment borrowed under user for loop-->
        {% for borrow in borrowed %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ borrow.eqp_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ borrow.eqp_serial }}</td>
            <td>{{ borrow.timestamp }}</td>
            <td>{{ borrow.return_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ borrow.purpose }}</td>
            <td>{{ borrow.details }}</td>
            <form method = "post">
            <td><button name="return">Return</button></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

I'd want it to look something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUMQ0.png). Once the button at the return column is clicked, the said equipment's SQL data will be updated to available, allowing other users to borrow it after.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes,** it is possible to add a button to the second table that allows users to return borrowed equipment by updating the data file in your SQL file.

**in index.html**

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ borrow.eqp_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ borrow.eqp_serial }}</td>
    <td>{{ borrow.timestamp }}</td>
    <td>{{ borrow.return_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ borrow.purpose }}</td>
    <td>{{ borrow.details }}</td>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="/return_equipment">
            <input type="hidden" name="eqp_serial" value="{{ borrow.eqp_serial }}">
            <button type="submit" name="return">Return</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**now Update app.py**

```
from flask import request, redirect, url_for

@app.route("/return_equipment", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def return_equipment():
    if request.method == "POST":
        eqp_serial = request.form.get("eqp_serial")

        # Update equipment availability to "available"
        db.execute("UPDATE equipments SET availability = 1 WHERE eqp_serial = ?", eqp_serial)
    # You may want to update the transaction or perform additional actions here.

return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

now, When a user clicks the "Return" button, a POST request to the /return_equipment endpoint with the equipment serial is sent. The server will then update the availability of the equipment in the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! really solved the issue was stuck on few weeks. I also added the transactions panel as suggested. thank again !